# ArcGIS JavaScript runtime map doesn't display

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I started following the code sample the Esri provided, but when I run it the map doesn't show up.

This is the link:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-mapview/index.html

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Get started with MapView - Create a 2D map</title>
<style>
  html, body, #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/"></script>
<script>
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, MapView){
  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "local"
  });
  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",  // Reference to the scene div created in step 5
    map: map,  // Reference to the map object created before the scene
    zoom: 4,  // Sets the zoom level based on level of detail (LOD)
    center: [15, 65]  // Sets the center point of view in lon/lat
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it off your local machine?  Images will not load if you are loading the file via its directory on the machine...  e.g. typing C:\Code\map.html into the address bar.

You will need to host the file using a simple web server (python, apache, iis) so that the requests for map tiles are made over http. You can then access your working map through http://localhost:8080/map.html or however you want to set it up.

Comment: I tried web server tomcate, stil the same probelm

Comment: What does the debugging console in your web browser say?  Also, try viewing the network responses and resources for the web tiles.

Is NOTHING show up?  Is the UI there?